# How do I add affiliate code to Magento 1.7 success page?

Tags: magento

For example, I need to include the below code in /checkout/success.phtml

"https://ad.vertiga.com/MM?adv_sub=CUSTOMER_ID&amount=AMOUNT"

Answer (score 0):

You can find success page by following this path: 
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/checkout/success.phtml

I tried following provided by you link for more instructions, but it is dead.
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

go to file \app\design\frontend\default\bcm\template\checkout\success.phtml and add your code.

OR

if you want to change the functionality got to app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\success.php      and change the as you have need.

Note: second step is not so good if you have knowledge of custom extension, create an custom extension and extend the checkout controller.
Refer: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part4-series-helloworld